# Why does my Sqlite database get really slow when one table gets a lot of records?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an Sqlite database on Android and if I put 2000 records in one table all the other tables get really slow.

With 2000 records in the one table I can run a 'SELECT COUNT(*)' on a table with 0 records and it can take anywhere from 5 to 30 seconds.

Comment: Do you have another thread/process writing to the database at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reasons for that. The usual reasons are:

1. Poorly written query
2. Not using a primary key, assuming one even exists on the table
3. Poorly designed data model (table structure)
4. Lack of indexes

IMO, your case may be lack of indexes. Check if you have indexed your tables/rows.

Answer (score -1):

"SELECT COUNT( * )", the char ' * ' need database to extract every field when sql execute.

As an additional suggest, you can use primary key in the " count( < your primary key > ) ".